# Spring context. Конфигурирование классов

Tags: java, spring, dependency-injection

Создал главный класс Main, класс `InjectionContext` и класс `Vk Bot`. Попытка управлять классом через инжекции не к чему не приводит. Ошибок нет, но и вывода сообщения нет. Подскажите пожалуйста в чем моя ошибка?

```
package reversbot;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext;

@SpringBootApplication
public class Main {

    public static void main(String... args) {
        ApplicationContext context = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext (InjectionContext.class);
    }

}
```

```java
package reversbot;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import reversbot.injectioncontext.VkBot;

import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;

@Configuration
public class InjectionContext {

    @Bean
    public VkBot vkBot() {
        return new VkBot();
    }
}
```

```
package reversbot.injectioncontext;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

@Service
public class VkBot {

    public static void hello(){
        System.out.println("Hello BOSS!!!!");
    }

}
```

```
plugins {
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '2.7.2'
    id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.0.12.RELEASE'
    id 'java'
}

group = 'ReversBot'
version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
sourceCompatibility = '18'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter'
    testImplementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test'
}

tasks.named('test') {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}
```

Comment: см: [Что делать с ответами на мой вопрос?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Comment: Вам не помог ответ?

Comment: помог, я вам плюсую, но еще плохо разбираюсь в правилах сообщества.

Comment: голоса принимаются только после того  как ваш рейтинг будет >= 15. до тех пор(и далее) слева от вопроса ставится галочка ( при условии что человек ответил на ваш вопрос ). Первое и последнее не связаны. Галочка показывает что на ваш вопрос ответили и показывает другим пользователям с подобным вопросами какой именно ответ вам помог. В общем галочка отвечает за статус и она ближе к обязательной ( при условии что человек ответил на ваш вопрос...если нет - то ставить не надо... ). А плюсик это уже выражение благодарности и одобрения.

Comment: поднял вам чуть рейтинг, чтобы вы могли спокойно голосовать за ответы. но про галочки тоже не забывайте. в противном случае участники просто перестанут отвечать на ваши вопросы.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Все правильно Spring делает.

Ничего не происходит, потому что **вы ничего не делаете**.
В том смысле, что вы ничего не вызываете.
Да, вы создаете бин `VkBot`...
Но он ничего не делает!
По всей видимости вы ждете что он выведет в консоль `Hello BOSS!!!!`, но он этого не сделает, потому что Вы не вызываете данный метод (я про метод `hello()`).
Он вообще в статическом методе находится!

Если хотите чтобы бин при создании выводил в консоль `Hello BOSS!!!!` - перенесите данный код в конструктор или инициализирующий метод.

```java
package reversbot.injectioncontext;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

@Service
public class VkBot {
    // создаем конструктор
    public VkBot() {
        // и переносим вызов сюда
        System.out.println("Hello BOSS!!!!");
    }

    // Убираем данные метод
    // public static void hello(){ 
    //      System.out.println("Hello BOSS!!!!");
    // }
}
```

и все начинает выводиться

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]